# Why query_vars get altered in WP_Query Object?

Tags: wp-query, query-variable

I am having problems when querying a WP_Query Object when a user has a role different than `administrator`

My WP_Query is this:

```
function remove_new_c_post($author_id,$value_id) {

        $query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
            'author' => $author_id,
            'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'value_id',
                    'value'   => $value_id,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
            ),
            'order' => 'ASC'

            ));

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            wp_delete_post( get_the_ID() );
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;

}
```

For some reason when the query is run by a user other than the administrator, this is the result:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [post_type] => custom_post_type
            [author] => 70
            [meta_query] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => AND
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => value_id
                            [value] => 86
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                )

            [order] => ASC
        )

    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [post_type] => custom_post_type
            [author] => 86 //<--- THIS SHOULD BE 70
            [meta_query] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => AND
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => value_id
                            [value] => 86
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                ) 
            [order] => ASC
...
```

Please notice the author in `query_vars` it is 86 when it should be 70. Why is this being altered?

**EDIT:**

I just tried to set the query_var `$query->set( 'author', $author_id );` and it kept the author_id intact; howevever, the mysql keeps getting altered:

```
  [request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  dlwp_posts.ID
               FROM dlwp_posts
               INNER JOIN dlwp_postmeta ON ( dlwp_posts.ID = dlwp_postmeta.post_id )   
               WHERE 1=1  AND dlwp_posts.post_author IN (86)
                 AND dlwp_posts.post_type = 'custom_post_type'
                 AND (dlwp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                   OR dlwp_posts.post_status = 'future'
                   OR dlwp_posts.post_status = 'draft'
                   OR dlwp_posts.post_status = 'pending'
                   OR dlwp_posts.post_status = 'private')
                 AND (( dlwp_postmeta.meta_key = 'value_id'
                   AND CAST(dlwp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%86%' )
```

Comment: where do you set `$author_id`?

Comment: I am passing it as a variable in the function through a custom hook. The thing is that it works ok when the user has admin rights.

Comment: you've verified that `$author_id` is `70` in both cases then before the query is run? the first step in debugging is figuring out where the point of failure is. you haven't shown enough code to determine if `$author_id` has the wrong value, or the change occurs within the query itself.

Comment: @Milo I just edited my question so you can see that `$author_id` doesnt change throughout the function.

Comment: @Milo even if I hardcode the ids in, the author id keeps changing. Maybe it has something to do with capabilities, but I logged in to the backend with another role other than administrator and I was able to delete the custom post type. So, the user has the capability to delete it.

Comment: then it would seem you have a `pre_get_posts` action or a query filter somewhere in your theme or a plugin that is capturing those queries and altering them.

Comment: @Milo I checked for possible `pre_get_posts` actions and other query filters and could not find any that was intercepting the query; however, I did fix the issue. When a user posts a custom post type, I wanted to assign another ID as an author of that custom post, for some reason, wordpress is not allowing me to delete that post afterwards. So, I just gave up and now I am setting the `author_id` with the user id that is making the custom post. I don't know if this is a matter of user role capabilities or just wordpress that doesnt allow a user to delete another's user post.

Answer (score 1):

[Milo's comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173664/why-query-vars-get-altered-in-wp-query-object#comment252627_173664) about `pre_get_posts` helped solve this issue for me. In my case the parent theme used the `pre_get_posts` action to explicitly set the `post_type` for all author pages. It wasn't in the functions.php, but I was able to find it by searching the theme for instances of `pre_get_posts`. (I used `grep -R "pre_get_posts" . -l` from the command line to find the file.)

If you're not using a child theme, you could potentially just delete the problematic function and its `add_action()`.

If you are using a child theme, to maintain upgradability of the parent theme, you can use the [remove_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) function...

**Problematic Action existing in Parent Theme:**

```
function problematic_parent_action( &$query ) {
  if ($query->is_author) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'problematic_parent_post_type' ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'problematic_parent_action' );
```

**Resolution added to Child Theme:**

```
function remove_problematic_parent_action() {
  remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'problematic_parent_action' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_problematic_parent_action');
```